# Problems using "require" with two script-tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function `loadDays()` that should be called when my `body` section is loaded:

```
<body onload="loadDays()">
```

My `loadDays()` function looks like this:

```
<script>
    function loadDays() {  
        // Code
    }
</script>
```

Inside of `loadDays()` I need to access an `excel`-file.

So I added `src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"` to the `<script>` tag.

But then I recieved the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loadDays is not defined at onload

---

Then someone gave me the hint to use two different `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js">
    const Excel = require('exceljs');
</script>

<script>
    function loadDays() {       
        // Code
    }
</script>
```

But now I have the problem that it says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Excel is not defined at loadDays

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, in your script you could use a 'DOMready' event :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

Everything inside this event will be executed once the full DOM is loaded

If you import well your script, that should do the trick